# trying to show user login as modal in angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5

i want to show my login component html file as modal in home page :

i have components like this:

```
app-⇩
  components-⇩
    about
    dashboard-⇩ admin
    footer      user
    home        useruser
    login
    navbar
```

and this is my app.components.html

```
<app-navbar>

</app-navbar>
<app-home></app-home>

  <router-outlet></router-outlet>


<app-footer></app-footer>
```

here is my navbar.html related code

```
<ul [hidden]="isAuthenticated()" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
  <li>
    <a class="waves-effect btn-flat" href="#">sign up</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="waves-effect btn-flat" href="#" id="login">login</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

this is the modal that login component is in it :

```
  <div id="modal1" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
       <app-login></app-login>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and the js file that should open the modal for me

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#login').click(function () {
      $('#modal1').show('open')
  })
});
```

i want to know where the modal code should be located to have this modal works properly if i put modal code in navbar html file .. if i click login button modal will apear behind some component

Comment: Are you trying to use jQuery? this is not going to work like that, you need to write component or find existing library for it, actually, I don't see any need for jQuery.

Comment: this modal coms from materializecss because im using materializecss and to open that modal i used this little jquery code

Comment: You still need to find a better way, have you looked into https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview if you want material? and `CSS` has nothing to do with `javascript` anyway, so you can use classes you want, and use any framework you want without being restricted because of "CSS".

Comment: @Al-Mothafar i saw that but that is material.angular and my project is angular 5  can i use that modal component here .. should i install somthing with npm ?

Comment: I think you really need to go with training path, first of all, seems you don't have even the basics, anyway, you need to follow this: https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Try looking into Angular Material modal

`npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk`

https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/examples

2. Try looking into NGB Modal

`npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap`

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples

Then you can create a new component, and put the modal view and code into that component's HTML and TS files respectively, and then just call that component in the `openModal()` function.

There are extensive guides on both of those links on how to implement the modal, both as a separate component or even as an inline modal in the navbar html.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "modal code"? If you are asking where to place the jQuery code, I am assuming you need to click on the Login Button in the navbar and the Login Modal appears. In that case, write a click event on login button,

```
 <a class="waves-effect btn-flat" href="#" id="login" (click)="openModal()">login</a>
```

In the component of the navbar, add

```
declare var $: any;
```

right under the import statements. Then inside the component class write the jquery code inside openModal() as follows:

```
openModal(){
    $('#modal1').show('open');
}
```

Make sure to include the jquery script in your html.

Comment: no i asked about modal code my mean this code :
`
  <div id="modal1" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
       <app-login></app-login>
    </div>
  </div>
`
i used js code in seprate file and it works good .
 but modal will appear behind of all component

Comment: Where have you put the code currently? My guess would be to put it in the app-navbar component, but again it depends on your entire Html structure. This is not an angular issue. The first component that gets called is the outer most html and so on. Does that help?